# How to identify a string starts and ends with a numeric value in PHP

Tags: php

I need to identify that a string starts and ends with a numeric value and 7 digit long.

Let- `1000453` or `0984567` . Those two string is start with a numeric value and end with a numeric value.If any string start with any character let say - `a234567`  than it show fail.

pls kindly suggest in PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you don't care if there are characters in the middle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use a regex for this:

```
$count = preg_match ('/^[0-9].{5}[0-9]$/', $value)
```

That basically gives you every string that starts and ends with a digit with any five characters in-between. `$count` is the number of matches found with non-zero meaning it matched.

If you want a different pattern, just adjust the regex. For example, seven characters, all numeric would be `'/^[0-9]{7}$/'`.

Keep in mind I'm old-school and still use `[0-9]` for digits since not all regex engines support the `\d` notation, but PHP should be okay with that (such as `'/^\d{7}$/'`).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want only numbers?

Then this should work

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{7}$/", $argv[1]))
  {
    echo "Ok";
  }
```

If you also want to have other possible values in the string the regex of paxdiablo is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$string = "984f1a3";

if(strlen($string) <= 7){
    if(!is_numeric(substr($string, 0, 1)) and !is_numeric(substr($string, strlen($string)-1, strlen($string)))) echo "FAIL";
    else echo "Success";
}
else echo "FAIL";
```

Answer (score 0):

is_numeric() is mildly risky. The string '1e5' might mean 10000 in scientific notation, but it might not.

Your problem calls for a regular expression.

```
/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
```

or the simpler

```
/[0-9]{7}/
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions using regular expressions above, the following should also do the job.  I haven't tested it though!

`$result = TRUE;`

if (strlen($string) == 7)
{
  $string_arr = str_split($string);
  if (!(ctype_digit($string_arr[0]] && ctype_digit($string_arr[6])))
    $result = FALSE;
}
else
  $result = FALSE;

return $result;